# How to add total obs. count per bin/bar as a summary stat (line) to "filled" geom_histogram in ggplot?

Tags: r, ggplot2, statistics, histogram, summary

Consider the following toy data

```
dat=data.frame(value=runif(3000,1,5),
            name=rep(c('A','B','C','D','E','F')),
            code=c(rep('game1',1500),rep('game2',1500))
            )
```

I am visualising it as a 100% stacked histogram using 'fill' from geom_histogram

```
ggplot(dat,aes(x=value))+
    geom_histogram(position='fill',binwidth=0.5,aes(fill=name))+
    theme_bw()+
    scale_fill_brewer(palette="RdBu")+
    facet_wrap(~code)
```

How to add the total number of observations per bin as a line using stat (..count..).
I tried stat_function with mean as a normal distribution overlayed on the top using dnorm, but just need simply a line summarizing the number of observations in each bin for both the facets.

1. per variable (A-E)
2. total

I also tried stat_bin with label=..count.., but it pushes the y limits to to itself and the bars are pushed down. What am I missing?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

First part was very easy actually. I could just calculate the count density using geom_density and add it as a line.

```
ggplot(dat,aes(x=value))+
    geom_histogram(position='fill',binwidth=0.5,aes(fill=name))+
    theme_bw()+
    scale_fill_brewer(palette="RdBu")+
    facet_wrap(~code)+geom_density(color='white',size=2)
```

[image]

For the second query, it doesn't make much sense. I changed the position to identity and I am using stat_bin to count the items per bin, but I want to add it as a line per condition, I will add it as a new question.